# in_caterogy won't show after changing publishing date/time

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress is behaving really strange here, beyond my understanding!

So having this 4 posts:
[image] 
And this is how I show them on my site:
[image]

As you can see, it only shows 3 posts from the 'Events' category. This is right! See code:

```
     if (have_posts())
            {
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    if (in_category( 'Events' )) {
                        $haveEvents = true;
                        **if ($eventCount < 3) {**
                            $eventCount++;
                            ?>
                            <div class="event-tile">
                                <div class="event-tile-content">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <h4><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h4>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="event-tile-read-more">Lees meer</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                endwhile;
            }
```

I also have some other categories en thereby I use multiple have_posts loops for showing the post from each category.

Now after I added some new posts for each category, the 'Event' posts where gone. I tested like an hour or so, and I found the problem, for some reason the loop have troubles to show 'older' posts (belonging to the 'events' category).

Here Ill demonstrate what I mean:
Changed the 'published' time, so the posts was the 'oldest':
[image]
After committing this change, the post was gone..
[image]

I don't understand this strange behaviour from Wordpress. 
As the code shows;

1. loop trow posts
2. If post in category 'Event' go on ->
3. if 'eventCount' smaller than 3 -> show
4. 'eventCount'++

Did I made a mistake? Is wordpress buggy here?

Comment: So you are looping over the results of the WP main query here? If so, it probably limits the number of posts shown on that page (so that you would have to paginate to see more/older posts.) In that case, this behavior is nothing but to be expected – you would need to change it so that the query delivers _all_ posts, without any pagination.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, could it be? I just find out it is not only in my event posts, but just the last 2 posts. Maybe there is some limit on the total posts in the have_posts loop!:o

Comment: btw, not sure if I use WP main query to be honest! Just using, if have posts -> while posts -> show post, but 3 times in one page..

Comment: Well you’re likely using the main query – otherwise you would have to call `have_posts` and `the_post` on a specific custom `WP_Query` instance to begin with. So you will need to configure WP to show _all_ posts without pagination for whatever page (front, archive, …?) it is that you’re on.

Comment: Yeah, just founded out there was 'Blog pages show at most' settings within the admin panel itself.. But is this a bad practice to loop true the posts? using main query?

Comment: i think wp archive pages limit posts to 10 by default, the problem is increasing this will really hammer load times. If you are using caching you could deal with this and maybe output json and loop through that, other than than use ajax to return the next set of posts. Google custom wp query to create custom loops.